# How to reset default permissions for downloaded files on Mac OSX (Mavericks)

Tags: macos, permissions, download

I'm the IT at a web dev e-commerce company, and my developers have been complaining lately about not being able to access images they download from emails and online. I checked out the file permissions, and sure enough any image that they download come with these permissions:

- rw- r-- ---@

I've had to go to their stations real quick and chmod the permissions for them, but we want to know why (suddenly) any files that are downloaded do not have "other" permissions enabled, and how we should fix this? chmod isnt a hard command to run, but they are not IT's and they ask before they do anything to make sure they do not mess anything up, and I also have things to do rather than change permissions constantly.

I know this isn't much to go off of, but i'll provide any information if requested. I'm just wondering if anyone else had permission issues like this before, and what steps i could take or where i should investigate in solving this.

Thank you!